# ISO8601 DateTime String to be displayed in local users timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, iso8601

I have an ISO8601 datetime string retrieved from the server in UTC and would like to display it in the users local time in the following format.

YYYY/MM/DD - Hour:Mins:Seconds

How can I do this in javascript/jquery? Using momentjs is also acceptable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString  This? Momentjs will have a similar function, but you'll have to look at the moment API for that,

Comment: using moment try this `moment(dateISOFormat ).format('YYYY/MM/DD - HH:mm:ss');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using momentjs try the following snippet

```
moment(dateISOFormat).format('YYYY/MM/DD - HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Hi it seems to be different by one hour to my local pc time on windows 10. The iso8601 to be parsed is in utc time so is not in local time to begin with maybe that wasnt clear from my question so I have edited it

Comment: Try this `var localTime = moment.utc(utcDate).toDate(); var formattedLocalTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY/MM/DD - HH:mm:ss');`